# Displaying less columns in serve-index node module

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to display a folder full of files form the inside of a server. I'm using the serve-index npm module to do so (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index).

My issue is that the file names I'm using are too long. Serve-index displays 3 columns at a time so it's hard to read the entire file name at a glance. Is there a way to display either 1 or 2 columns?

Comment: Read the docs, it says You can use custom template. Or read the source code to see how it works. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Molda said, it was all css based. All I need was to specify a custom css file in express like the following.

`app.use('/text_files', serveIndex(__dirname + '/text_files', {'stylesheet':'./styles/directories.css'}));`